# Sql server Query to get the Table Altered Result

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table as below

```
ClientID        AccountNumber   BalanceOnDay0       BalanceOnDay1   BalanceOnDay2       BalanceOnDay3       BalanceOnDay4       BalanceOnDay5       BalanceOnDay6       BalanceOnDay7
ABC1            123             10                  NULL            NULL                NULL                NULL                NULL                NULL                NULL    
ABC1            123             NULL                NULL            NULL                NULL                NULL                NULL                NULL                3
```

I would like to see the result as beblow.

```
ClientID        AccountNumber   BalanceOnDay0       BalanceOnDay1   BalanceOnDay2       BalanceOnDay3       BalanceOnDay4       BalanceOnDay5       BalanceOnDay6       BalanceOnDay7
ABC1            123             10                  NULL            NULL                NULL                NULL                NULL                NULL                3
```

Please suggest!

Comment: Very poorly designed table :(.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SUM()` if you want to combine the balance values, if you have multiple records:

```
select clientid,
  accountnumber,
  sum(BalanceOnDay0) BalanceOnDay0, 
  sum(BalanceOnDay1) BalanceOnDay1, 
  sum(BalanceOnDay2) BalanceOnDay2,
  sum(BalanceOnDay3) BalanceOnDay3,
  sum(BalanceOnDay4) BalanceOnDay4, 
  sum(BalanceOnDay5) BalanceOnDay5,
  sum(BalanceOnDay6) BalanceOnDay6, 
  sum(BalanceOnDay7) BalanceOnDay7
from table1
group by clientid, accountnumber
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e487f/1)